# After Adding quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar file in project libs folder and getting error when install on device

Tags: android, jar-signing, quickblox

when add `quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar` in My Project `libs` folder then I'm getting an error. I have done all related for it like update `Adt`  to `21`, bin delete and clean, restart Eclipse etc but not working. Also in my project 13 jar files contains. here Only `quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar` is getting issue.dependency issue and Multiple dex files issue.pls help me. facing issue from last 4 days

below jar files using in Project `libs` folder contains

```
    apache-mime4j-0.6.jar
    asmack-android-7
    gcm.jar
    httpmime-4.1.2.jar
    jtwitter.jat
    PayPal_MPL.jar
    quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar
    signpost-commonshttp4-1.2.1.1.jar
    signpost-core-1.2.1.1.jar
    signpost-jetty6-1.2.1.1.jar
    twitter4j-core-android-2.2.6.jar
    universal-image-loader-1.6.1-with-src.jar
    android-support-v4.jar
```

error log

```
[2013-05-10 17:59:02 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;
[2013-05-10 17:59:02 - Lockme] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;
[2013-05-10 17:59:20 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;
[2013-05-10 17:59:20 - Lockme] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;
```

In simple when i'm adding this jar file then project not working and when Remove this jar file from Project then load (run) project well and able to install on device and Emulator, this may simple issue but coudnot resolve it.

```
Project.properties

# Project target.
target=Google Inc.:Google APIs:17
android.library.reference.3=../ImageViewTouch
android.library.reference.4=../android-pulltorefresh-master/pulltorefresh
android.library.reference.1=../android-mapviewballoons
android.library.reference.2=../../Android/android-sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows/android-sdk-windows/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib
```

java Build[image]

Java Order - and Export[image]

Error Image [image]

Comment: Can you post your project.properties file?

Comment: yes pls check it @shoerat

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a list of libs which uses Android QB SDK http://quickblox.com/developers/Android#How_to:_add_SDK_to_IDE_and_connect_to_the_cloud

You can remove your lib and it will be used from QB SDK

[no need in libs except Quick blox see](http://image.quickblox.com/f924e0e1dc10f3a479bbde3e9d93.injoit.png)

Comment: ok let me check you can also see by all jar files details in Image

Comment: It is not always possible to use this fix. I have flurryagent jar in my project. It contains org/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart. And QB also contains it. I cannot remove flurryagent, it contains functionality needed by my app.

Comment: The only way I found is to repack conflicting jar to remove duplicating classes. jar -xvf ./your.jar; rm -fr conflicting/classes; jar -cvf ./your.jar com META*

Answer (score 2):

make sure you're NOT adding it in BOTH places (libs folder AND project properties=>java build path). It should be in one or the other, otherwise you will get DEX errors. I just spent two days chasing down the exact same (looking) problem with the google maps.jar.  In the end all it was was this double reference that turned out to be the culprit. Not sure that's the problem you're facing, but it's a good place to start :)

Comment: i have put it in libs and add into java build path in both

Comment: right... that's going to cause a problem. remove it from one or the other.

Comment: only one jar file have issue quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar is main issue in myproject

Comment: not sure what to tell you... that was the solution to my problem. I guess it's possible yours is something else. Make sure to clean your project and fix project properties between your various attempts to solve it.

Comment: when quickblox-android-0.8.1.jar remove from project libs and build path then project working fine, so i m also not getting it.

Comment: @AnkitMakwana, can you verify if any of your additional libraries has a reference to quickblox lib/jar?

Comment: no its only one Quickblox m using and also unique, you can see all my jar details in my quetion.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't have any other solutions. I know for a fact that in my case the problem was caused by what I described above. If you're sure that the duplicate lib reference isn't causing it, then unfortunately I have no other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer for `Multiple dex files define Lorg/apache/http/entity/mime/FormBodyPart;`

i advice you to this problem occur in two type lib references in project.one is use in the **JavaBuildpath  ---> Libraies**

and another is in **JavaBuildpath ----> Order and Export--> Android dependencis.**

so i advice first remove the dependencies and after clean and run.problem slove.

Comment: for java build and javaorder

Comment: @AnkitMakwana then remove the depedencies click in asmack-android-7.jar unselected.then do as my answer.